# groovy + how to export PATH

Tags: groovy

In some groovy script I added this line:

```
def JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.7.0_60
```

because I get error as

```
groovy: JAVA_HOME not set and cannot find javac to deduce location, please setJAVA_HOME.
```

But this did not help.

What’s wrong with this line:

```
def JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.7.0_60
```

or maybe need to use export, but don’t know how to do this in groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is fine with this line but it just defines a variable named `JAVA_HOME`. In JVM it's **not possible** to export user defined environment variables.

But if it was possible the following code would do the trick:

```
System.getenv().put('JAVA_HOME', 'path_to_java_home')
```

You need to define environment variable on the OS level.